# Is there any way to add pagination to a table, which fetches data from database?

Tags: database, pagination, paging, semantic-ui

I am experiencing huge trouble with table pagination. I searched every YouTube video, 10 pages of Google with "Table pagination", but none worked for me. My table has Semantic UI styling (class) and fetches data from Database. I have no clue, how to add pagination to this table. Also I tried JQuery plugins and so on, but that doesn't work.

Comment: How about code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [datatables plugin](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html). It comes with lots of features along with pagination options.

### HTML file

```
<div>
  <table id="myTable">
    <thead> <tr>..</tr></thead>
    <?php
        Use php to populate table 
        foreach row fetched from database table
        {
        ?>
         <tr>
             <td>data1</td> 
             <td>data1</td>
         </tr>
        <?php
        }

    ?>

</div>


.....
```

### In JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable( {
        "ordering": false,
        "info":     false,
        ....
    } );
} );
```

Comment: It seems to me, that it doesnt support database.

Comment: Are you using those data in any kind of html or php or jsp page?

Comment: I am showing this table in php. With Semantic UI styling(doesnt metter really)

Comment: Hey you just fetch all the data and then just paginate when you instatiate the table (which you show to browser window )

Comment: And the question-how? :D Honestly, i tried everything, but with database I cant find any example..

Comment: @NaveUnown.: Ok you know how to fetch data from database using php ? (You set up a db connection then create a query..execute it..get the resultset...etc)..Then you just add the table in the html page and using javascript just instantiate it with options like paginate..number of pages, export to pdf excel etc..and then you are done...( just add the necesary rows).

Comment: Well, I have nearly everything, what you said(table is shown in my accounts.php file), except "instantiate".. Have no Idea, what is that and how to do it. Searched Google- no info, or I am stupid 0_0

Comment: You can use javascript in php?

Comment: Of course I can. But what do I need to write there?.. /_/

Comment: Ty :D If you need my code-I will send you. Just say!

Comment: @NaveUnown.: check this

Comment: THAT WORKS!!! How can I appreciate your help? You are the only one, who helped me!

Comment: @NaveUnown.: For now you can select my answer and later when you get enough repuation upvote me..LOL :D